# Prevent Drag & Drop When Scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, drag-and-drop, scroll

I am working on a Wpf project, but right now I'm stucked with a `ListView` issue.

Turns out that I have implemented a `Drag&Drop` functionality on the ListView that works fine. The problem comes when I try to scroll down or up. By doing this the `Drag&Drop` functionality gets activated preventing me from keeping scrolling.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583234/disable-drag-and-drop-when-scrolling) which indicates that we need to attach our control to the `ScrollChanged` event.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="listView1_ScrollChanged"...
```

but I really dont know what to do in that handler. **How could I disable the Drag&Drop from that event?? And How could I enable it again?? Or, is there a better way to solve this??**

That is my `Drag&Drop` Code:

```
 private void listView1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Store the mouse position
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
    }

    private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the current mouse position
        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;

        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
            (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
            Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
        {
            // Get the dragged ListViewItem
            ListView listView = sender as ListView;

            // Get items to drag
            var a = listView.SelectedItems;

            // Initialize the drag & drop operation
            DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myFormat", a);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listView, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
        } 
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe if you enlighten us how exactly you implemented that  drag drop functionality..

Comment: @Georgi-it Code added

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the MouseMove event if you are not in a MouseDown event:

```
bool stopDrag = true;
     private void listView1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Store the mouse position
            startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
stopDrag = false;
        }

        private void listView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
if(stopDrag)
   return;

            // Get the current mouse position
            Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
            Vector diff = startPoint - mousePos;

            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
                (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
            {
                // Get the dragged ListViewItem
                ListView listView = sender as ListView;

                // Get items to drag
                var a = listView.SelectedItems;

                // Initialize the drag & drop operation
                DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myFormat", a);
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listView, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
            } 
        }

private void listView1_MouseUp(...)
{
stopDrag = true;
}
```

This should work, I wrote it in the browser so excuse me if i did something wrong and for the formatting, I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Hi, I just tried it, but it didn't work, It keeps behaving the same way :(

Comment: In theory it should be working, maybe if you debug it and give me some additional info..

Comment: I did that, and the problem here is that when I press the mouse left button the `stopDrag` becomes `false`, so, when it gets the `listView1_MouseMove` method, the condition `if(stopDrag) return` is not met. I could invert the condition, but by doing that the Drag&Drop functionality is never started since my Drag&Drop functionality starts in the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event getting the position of the mouse

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple method to confirm whether the drag operation is confirmed or not using the `SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance` and `SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance` that were made for this purpose:

```
private bool IsDragConfirmed(Point point)
{
    bool horizontalMovement = Math.Abs(point.X - dragStartPosition.X) > 
         SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance;
    bool verticalMovement = Math.Abs(point.Y - dragStartPosition.Y) > 
         SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance;
    return (horizontalMovement | verticalMovement);
}
```

It is called in the `PreviewMouseMove` event... here is a simplified example:

```
private void DragSourcePreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isMouseDown && IsDragConfirmed(e.GetPosition(sender as ListBox)))
    {
        // Start your drag operation here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue and the same source as answers below.
Well I've decided to prevent dragging if mouse position is not over the listview items (rect 0, 0, lv.width - scroll.width, lv.height - scroll.height)
So I have a "allowdrag" flag, that becomes True if mouse pointer is over necessary rect when PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown elapsed.

VB.NET

```
Private allowdrag As Boolean

Private Sub lv_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles lvAttributesDefault.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown
    Dim listView As ListView = TryCast(sender, ListView)
    allowdrag = e.GetPosition(sender).X < listView.ActualWidth - SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth And e.GetPosition(sender).Y < listView.ActualHeight - SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight
End Sub

Private Sub lv_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lvAttributesDefault.MouseMove
    Dim listView As ListView = TryCast(sender, ListView)

    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed And listView.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing And allowdrag Then
        Dim obj As clsAttribute = CType(listView.SelectedItem, clsAttribute)
        Dim dragData As New DataObject("clsAttribute", obj)

        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listView, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    End If
End Sub
```

C# (telerik code converter)

```
private bool allowdrag;
private void lv_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;
    allowdrag = e.GetPosition(sender).X < listView.ActualWidth - SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth & e.GetPosition(sender).Y < listView.ActualHeight - SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight;
}

private void lv_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;

    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed & listView.SelectedItem != null & allowdrag) {
        clsAttribute obj = (clsAttribute)listView.SelectedItem;
        DataObject dragData = new DataObject("clsAttribute", obj);

        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listView, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

PS. clsAttribute is my custom class. The
listview has binding to ObservableCollection(Of clsAttribute)